# Как переподписать приложение, уже опубликованное в Google Play

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, apk

Достались исходники приложения, оно опубликовано в Google Play, внес свои исправления и хочу опубликовать новую версию? Могу ли я подписать его своим release ключом или мне нужен ключ, которым оно было подписано изначально?

Comment: Если уже залито и подписано другим ключом, нужен тот старый ключ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужен ключ которым оно уже было подписано.
Если подпишите новым ключом, то вам не дадут залить новую версию.

Если нет ключа то нужно удалить старую версию, поменять package_name и подписать новым ключом (по сути создать совершенно другое приложение).

Comment: Спасибо, все понял, буду выпрашивать старый ключ.

Comment: @AlexanderLomovskiy, если вам дан правильный ответ, отметьте его ,как правильный.